# .Net Reflector not properly linking resources

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

Ive decompiled a library but when i try to run it, anything that requests something from the resource manager doesnt work properly leaving me with "{"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"Logistics.Products.LayerPicking.Properties.Resources.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"LayerPicking.PBG\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}"

```
 [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    internal static System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (resourceMan== null)
            {
                System.Resources.ResourceManager manager = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("Logistics.Products.LayerPicking.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);  
                resourceMan = manager;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=OKGQRD3O

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the decompiling changed the name.  The Resource looks like it is LayerPicking.PBG.KUKARoboter.Logistics.Products.LayerPicking.Properties.Resources - notice the "LayerPicking.PBG." - which is the name of your project.

VS.Net likes to add the default namespace of the project to the beginning of the resources when it embeds them.

So here are 2 options (you can do either one - I would recommend #1):

1. Change your default namespace to KUKARoboter and rename your resx files to start with Logistics (not KUKARoboter).
2. Search for the "KUKARoboter.Logistics string and add in your default namespace to the string so it reads like the string it is looking for "LayerPicking.PBG.KUKARoboter.Logistics"